# When, if ever, should an association's ID be used directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have a `User` model, a `Task` model that `belongs_to :user`, `:has_one :event`, has a `completed` boolean attribute, and an `Event` model that is created when a task is completed, and also `belongs_to :event`.

In the `TaskObserver` I've noticed that instead of

```
# app/controllers/task_observer.rb
class TaskObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
def after_update(task)
  def after_update
    task.create_event(:user=>task.user) if task.completed?
  end
end
```

I could write

`task.create_event(:user_id=>task.user.id)`

or even

`task.create_event(:user_id=>task.user_id)`

While the first way seems the most correct, are there benefits to using either of the latter variations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case I went with `task.create_event(:user_id=>task.user_id)`. By running:

```
$ rails c
ruby-1.8.7-p299 > ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ruby-1.8.7-p299 > Task.where("user_id IS NOT NULL).user.id
...
User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 103) LIMIT 1
=> 103
```

you can see that Rails will actually load the `User` from the database. Even if it *was* cached, I don't see why I should handle the actual objects if I'm just copying a reference.

So in general, I think it's preferred to use objects when you've used them before, and IDs when you didn't and don't plan to.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails, associations can be assigned either way, neither is "right" or "wrong" and it's just the nature of the framework. The models has setter methods for both `user_id` and `user`, which is why you can use either without any noticeable difference.

The way you are creating events seems a little strange to me though. It seems really odd that a task would belong_to an event, but the event is only created when the task is complete. Is that really how it works?

Comment: That's really how it works. Do you think has_one is more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

As Beerlington said - there is no "right" or "wrong" here - perhaps a performance consideration to be had however...

In the task.user.id case, if the user isn't eager-loaded, you're making a round trip to the database; in the task.user_id case, you're not making that round trip....

- Note - Rails is probably smart enough to notice that if you're just grabbing id off the association it can just use task.user_id - but I haven't gone to great lengths to confirm this. Would be easy enough to check against the development.log....